How to store render pass attachment without ending the render pass in Metal
I would like to sample from one of the attachments of the render pass in a shader. But attachments are written to the memory at the end of the render pass, which means I would have to create a new render pass for every draw call to ensure that it always has the latest contents. However, that is pretty expensive, since all the attachments would be stored and then loaded in the next render pass.
So is it possible to store just 1 attachment without ending the render pass? I was thinking about using a tile shader to access the tile memory and write it to the main memory, but I am unsure if it’s valid to write to a texture that is used in the current render pass.
Also, I know that this is probably not a good idea and I should just use programmable blending, but I am making an emulator, and that would require analyzing the shader code to potentially promote texture sampling to framebuffer fetch, so not really worth it.
Thanks in advance!

It’s not possible

@Spo1ler not even with tile shaders?

You can only get a single tile in tile shader. You don't know when all the tiles are gonna "finish" doing their thing. If you need the resulting texture, you need to end the pass.
